# Prevent Ant from performing a task if a file is older than another file

Tags: java, ant, timestamp

how can I prevent Ant from processing a task if a source file is older than the current target.  For example, I created a **javacc** file `MyParser.jj` and there is no need for javacc to re-generate the file MyParser.java as long as the `MyParser.jj` is older than `MyParser.java`.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing is changing the file in a way that makes its last change time appear to be later ?

Comment: Note: The javacc was just an example. I was looking for a general way to prevent a task to be executed if the source is older than the result.

Comment: Then I would edit the question to use a different example, just to be more clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aaron said, the `javacc` task shouldn't be executed on code that hasn't changed.

But, to answer to original question - there's an [**`uptodate`**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) task that can be used for this purpose. Here's an [example](http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/AntUptodate.html).

Answer (score 2):

There must be a bug elsewhere or your version of Ant is too old. [From the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javacc.html):

> This task only invokes JavaCC if the grammar file is newer than the generated Java files.